# Echo Nest API: convert curl command for checking rate limit to c#

Tags: c#, php, api, curl, echonest

I'm trying to convert this curl command to c#

```
curl -i 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=[API KEY]&name=weezer'
```

This returns a response header with content like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 135
X-RateLimit-Limit: 120
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 62
X-RateLimit-Used: 58
```

I tried this code but when I run it, it gets an exception: "HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed".

```
string baseurl = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=[API KEY]&name=weezer";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=http://www.google.com";
    streamWriter.Write(data);
}

var response = request.GetResponse();
string text;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your `Method` to `GET`.

Comment: I tried that, but now it gets Protocol Violation Exception.

Comment: Why are you using a `StreamWriter`? An HTTP GET doesn't typically have a payload. Try removing the whole `using` block.

Comment: I removed it. It works, but the response doesn't have the response header.

Comment: Remove `request.ContentType` since you are not sending any payload. Set `request.Accept = "*/*";`

Comment: Still no response header.

Comment: I am not a C# dude, but shouldn't the headers come in something like `response.Headers`?

Comment: It got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the changes Daniel suggested, I would remove the UserAgent.  After that, it looks pretty much like the C# I'm using successfully.  Here's a somewhat shortened version of that:

```
    string baseurl = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/profile?api_key=[API KEY]&name=weezer";
    var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    req.Accept = "application/json";

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream != null)
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var remaining = GetRateInfo(response.Headers, "X-RateLimit-Remaining");
                var used = GetRateInfo(response.Headers, "X-RateLimit-Used");
                var limit = GetRateInfo(response.Headers, "X-RateLimit-Limit");
                Trace.WriteLine($"Excedeed EchoNest Limits: remaining {remaining} - used {used} - limit {limit}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Error handling
        }
```

// And the header parsing code:

```
    private static int GetRateInfo(WebHeaderCollection headers, string type)
    {
        var s = headers.Get(type);
        if (s == null)
            return -1;

        int info;
        return int.TryParse(s, out info) ? info : -1;
    }
```